# set.addAll doesn't work with SObjectType

Tags: apex

I was trying to use set.addAll method with a list of SObject, but I was not able to make it work. Is there any restriction with this data type?

Documentation doesn't mention any: [Salesforce Set methods doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex230/Content/apex_methods_system_set.htm)

```
List<String> myList = new List<String>{'Test1','Test2','Test3'};
System.debug(myList);
Set<String> mySet = new Set<String>();
Boolean areInserted = mySet.addAll(myList);
System.debug(areInserted);
System.debug(mySet);
System.debug('Check with SObjectType');
Schema.DescribeFieldResult productFieldResult = Schema.sObjectType.MyObject__c.fields.Product__c;
List<SObjectType> fieldResults = productFieldResult.getReferenceTo();
System.debug(fieldResults);
Set<SObjectType> fieldResultsSet = new Set<SObjectType>();
Boolean areInserted2 = fieldResultsSet.addAll(fieldResults);
System.debug(areInserted2);
System.debug(fieldResultsSet);
System.debug('Try with loop');
List<SObjectType> mySet2 = new List<SObjectType>();
for(SObjectType objType : fieldResults)
{
    mySet2.add(objType);
}
System.debug(mySet2);
```

Finds here the debug result.

[image]

Thanks,
Agustina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the subject of whether contains works or not, I couldn't find a failing case with these simple tests (whether using standard or custom objects):

```
@isTest
private class SetTest {

    @isTest
    static void containsAndAddAll() {

        Set<SObjectType> s = new Set<SObjectType>{
                Contact.SObjectType,
                Account.SObjectType
                };
        assertContactAndAccountOnly(s);

        Set<SObjectType> ss = new Set<SObjectType>();
        ss.addAll(s);
        assertContactAndAccountOnly(ss);
    }

    private static void assertContactAndAccountOnly(Set<SObjectType> s) {

        System.assertEquals(false, s.contains(Task.SObjectType));
        System.assertEquals(true, s.contains(Contact.SObjectType));
        System.assertEquals(true, s.contains(Account.SObjectType));
        System.assertEquals(false, s.contains(Note.SObjectType));
        System.assertEquals(2, s.size());
    }

    @isTest
    static void addAndRemove() {

        Set<SObjectType> s = new Set<SObjectType>();

        // Add
        System.assertEquals(0, s.size());
        s.add(Note.SObjectType);
        System.assertEquals(1, s.size());
        s.add(Task.SObjectType);
        System.assertEquals(2, s.size());
        System.assertEquals(true, s.contains(Task.SObjectType));
        System.assertEquals(true, s.contains(Note.SObjectType));

        // Remove
        s.remove(Note.SObjectType);
        System.assertEquals(1, s.size());
        System.assertEquals(true, s.contains(Task.SObjectType));
        System.assertEquals(false, s.contains(Note.SObjectType));
        s.remove(Task.SObjectType);
        System.assertEquals(0, s.size());
        System.assertEquals(false, s.contains(Task.SObjectType));
        System.assertEquals(false, s.contains(Note.SObjectType));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are adding set.addAll(Set<SObjectType>) and my issue was with set.addAll(List<SObjectType>). However y tried again and works now. Apologize.

Answer (score 9):

The problem you are seeing is that for some reason the string representation of `Set` and `List` when they contain `SObjectType` is wrong making it appear that they are empty. If you invoke other methods such as `size` or `contains` you will see the behaviour you expect. Your test hints at that by `addAll` returning true.

I'd call this behaviour a bug, but I don't think the string representation is documented anywhere...

A work around (to help with debugging) would be to write a utility method that builds the string representation by iterating over the content and appending to a string e.g.:

```
public class Util {
    public static String toString(Set<SObjectType> sobTypes) {
        return toString(new List<SObjectType>(sobTypes));
    }
    public static String toString(List<SObjectType> sobTypes) {
        // Note that String.join doesn't work here at present
        String s = '';
        for (SObjectType sobType : sobTypes) {
            if (s != '') {
                s += ', ';
            }
            s += sobType;
        }
        return '{' + s + '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah beat me to it Keith! Nice one!

Comment: @AndrewFawcett Think I'd seen this problem in my own debugging before - a real time waster.

Comment: Yeah I can imagine, btw, rollout the new String.join function in your above example to make a little leaner... ;-)

Comment: @AndrewFawcett Aaargh keep doing this. I'll change it thanks.

Comment: @AndrewFawcett Tried String.join for a couple of SObjectTypes and it output "{common.apex.runtime.impl.ApexSObjectTypeToken@6d95f8ef, common.apex.runtime.impl.ApexSObjectTypeToken@110a4b1e}"; looks like the handling of these tokens is broken in more than one place...

Comment: Yikes! Indeed!!

Comment: Actually I needed to use the contains method and it returned to me false although the value should be there. I have scalate it to salesforce and post here the reply. Anyway thanks a lot for the suggestions.

Comment: @AgustinaGarcía Sorry to hear that. I had a go to create a failing test and couldn't - see extra answer. If you can report your bug in the form of a self contained short failing test, it is more likely to get prompt attention from Salesforce (and helps you confirm for yourself that there is definitely a bug).

Comment: @KeithC, I have the confirmation from Salesforce. This is a bug. If you have a set with SObjectType and you try to show the elements via System.debug, it doesn't work.